# Tools to put into place for designing for yourself

Tags: website-design, workflow

I know I am my worst enemy from critique to execution.  I ask this question because I wanted to know any good ways to stop myself from going on and on in my own work.  I have several ideas and things I'd like to design but I realized last year I only completed sketches and drafts and never really followed through with my personal projects or goals.  Its easier when you are working for a client and it helps when you have a design process, I get that, but when you are your own client what do you do?  I've heard some that will outsource to a friend but I feel to me I'm telling myself I cant design for myself if I did that.  So the question is when designing for yourself, what do you put into place to prevent yourself from disaster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collaboration.

We tend to work by ourselves, guarding our creative processes as if they were gems. If you have the chance to work with others, you can not only share the questions and doubts you might encounter in the process, but also push each other to complete things. Creating projects collaboratively can also give you unexpected and fascinating results.

Investments.

If you make an investment, even a tiny one (if it's a web project, it could be the purchasing of hosting + domain), you will most likely feel much more committed to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Deadlines.

I've found I must treat any self-promotional project the same way I would any project from a client. With full spec' sheets, timeframes, budgets, and deadlines.